# Why winform Dispose method is missing 'detect redundant calls'?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Why winform Dispose method is **missing  'detect redundant calls'**?

**Winform now Dispose method:**

```
   protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

---

**Why not this?**

```
    private bool disposedValue = false; //To detect redundant calls
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
               components.Dispose();
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not expressing a problem, only asking for clarification of, apparently, tool generated code.

Comment: As hvd points out, Dispose can be called multiple times and shouldn't be treated as an error - but we actually know that doing so is almost always a symptom of a mistake somewhere - so why are you trying to *optimize* an "error" path?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever But if there are 'unmanaged objects', I think there should be a `disposedValue`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasonable positions to take.

- `Dispose` can be called twice. This is supported by the documentation and suggests there is no need for your `disposedValue` check.
- `Dispose` should not be called twice. But then the form should not be disposed twice either, and if it's not, there is equally no need for your `disposedValue` check.

A `disposedValue` check inside `Dispose` only makes sense if some child object has a buggy implementation of `Dispose` that you want to work around.

Comment: I agree with '_if some child object has a buggy implementation of Dispose that you want to work around._'. I want to continue to do`Dispose`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `disposedValue` or other mechanism only if you have your own elements to free, managed or unmanaged does not matter.

If the only work you do on `Dispose` is to call other's `Dispose` you don't need to do anything as they will allow reentrancy (if they are correctly implemented).

So in this particular case you wrote you don't need to use the 'disposedValue' flag.

Having said that the most common implementation patterns for Dispose contains such flag (as a protected property to be able to use it from inheritors).

Comment: I agree with '_You need to have a disposedValue or other mechanism only if you have your own elements to free, managed or unmanaged does not matter._'.